# It all could have been different; It could all have been different; It could have all been different

Tags: grammar, word-order

Where would it be best to place the "all" (or any other word, for that matter) in this situation, and why?

These are all made-up sentences.

- It all could have [could've] been different/ played out differently.
- It could all have been different/ played out differently.
- It could have [could've] all been different/ played out differently.
- Come to think of it, I think one could even say " It could've been all different"

---

They all sound good to my ear, but I'd probably go, more often than not, with the third one.
I was thinking- maybe it has something to do with stress? (I never would've done that; I would never have done that; I would've never done that ).

---

Here's the same 'quote' worded differently (as above) in different newspapers:

- "'We could have all done better': White House admits[...]" ([The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/rob-porter-abuse-allegations-white-house-admits-it-could-have-done-better-a8201756.html))
- "'We all could have done better': White House spokesman admits [...]" ([Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/erik-wemple/wp/2018/02/08/we-all-could-have-done-better-white-house-spokesman-admits-fault-will-he-ever-again-appear-at-the-podium/?utm_term=.57c8fa037d27))

  Also: "It all could have been different. It should have been different" - [Rosa Vetrano, In the Olive Yard.](https://books.google.ro/books?id=pQdZDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT109&dq=it%20all%20could%27ve%20been%20different&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOstKylaPZAhVJ2CwKHdZ0CXkQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=it%20all%20could've%20been%20different&f=false)

Comment: The Independent have got it wrong, IMO.

Comment: Particularly since they're made-up sentences I for one think this belongs somewhere such as English Language Learners.

Comment: Except for the newspaper quotes (which, OK, *might* have been made up, ...)

Comment: Robbie, thanks for your input. Most helpful. You'll have noticed, of course, that there are three quotes pulled straight out of newspapers and a book.

Comment: More importantly, did you notice that Independent article doesn't contain those words? Just like the Washington Post, the Independent used "we all could have done better".

I confess I was too interested in the early part to notice those newspaper "quotes"… it'a also true that a single swallow doth not a summer make, even when the little beggar is observed in three different behaviours.

Presumably Vetrano had the time Shah didn't, to think about very word. To me it's obvious both would have been better using "could all have done/been…" but you pays your money and you takes your choice.

Answer (score -1):

It all could have been different.
We all could have done better.
it depends on what "all" means.

Think:  It all and all better have a different meaning

It could have been much better, (not all better)
It could involve all kinds of risk
It could have been all kinds of
All could have been better.

Answer (score -2):

I would propose, to avoid *any* confusion, saying *it could have been **completely different*** or *it could have turned out **completely different**[**ly**]*.